# Separate the list of acronyms in the glossary (glossaries)

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

In my thesis I would like to enter a list of acronyms and a glossary. I'm trying to do with the package `glossaries.` However, I meet a problem in separating the first from the second. If I use the option `acronym` for the `glossaries` package, I get the following error message is (which by the way does not seem to cover package `glossaries`):

> \tf@toc=\write14 \openout14 = `TESI.toc'.
>
> \tf@lof=\write15 \openout15 = `TESI.lof'.
>
> ! No room for a new \write . \alloc@ ...else \errmessage {No room for
>   a new #2} \fi \fi  l.147 \end{document}
>
> This error message was generated by an \errmessage command, so I can't
>   give any explicit help. Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine
>   all clues, and deduce the truth by order and method.
>
> ! Missing number, treated as zero.   \tf@lot  l.147
>   \end{document}
>
> A number should have been here; I inserted `0'. (If you can't figure
>   out why I needed to see a number, look up`weird error' in the index
>   to The TeXbook.)
>
> \openout0 = `.tex'.
>
> Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line
>   147. [201
>
> ] Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line
>   147. (./TESI.aux) Package atveryend Info: Executing hook`AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 147. Package atveryend Info:
>   Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 147. Package
>   rerunfilecheck Info: Checksums for`TESI.out': (rerunfilecheck)
>   Before: 6858287EFF9067DC2B2F35821F921A46;16384 (rerunfilecheck) After:
>   39B0DF222BB6E30662BA0A306FB5451C;26306. Package logreq Info: Writing
>   requests to 'TESI.run.xml'. \openout1 = `TESI.run.xml'.

Consider the following code:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% !TEX program = pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\acronimo}[1]{%
  \mbox{\sffamily\scshape\MakeLowercase{#1}}}

\usepackage{xcolor}
    \colorlet{grigioScuro}{gray!75!black}
    \colorlet{grigioChiaro}{gray!95!black}
    \colorlet{grigioSfondo}{gray!12!white}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 0,pdfstartpage=1,pdftitle={Titolo PDF},pdfauthor={Nome Cognome},hidelinks,unicode}

\usepackage{xifthen,xkeyval,xfor,amsgen}
\usepackage[toc,acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols} %su più colonne

%\newglossary[alg]{acronym}{acr}{acn}{\acronymname}
\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textcolor{gray}{\textsf{\MakeLowercase #1}}}
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{{\color{grigioScuro}\sffamily\scshape\MakeLowercase #1}}
\addto\captionsitalian{%
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{Glossario}%
 \renewcommand*{\acronymname}{Acronimi}%
 \renewcommand*{\entryname}{Nomenclatura}%
 \renewcommand*{\descriptionname}{Descrizione}%
 \renewcommand*{\symbolname}{Simbolo}%
 \renewcommand*{\pagelistname}{Elenco delle pagine}%
 \renewcommand*{\glssymbolsgroupname}{Simboli}%
 \renewcommand*{\glsnumbersgroupname}{Numeri}
}

\ProvidesDictionary{glossaries-dictionary}{Italian}
\providetranslation{Glossary}{Glossario}

\renewcommand*{\glossaryentrynumbers}[1]{\quad #1}

    %su più colonne
    \renewcommand*{\glsmcols}{2}
    \glossarystyle{mcolindex}

\newacronym{fem}{fem}{Finite Element Method}

\newglossaryentry{nomeVoce}{name={nome voce},description={Descrizione della voce}}

\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\printglossary

\gls{fem}. E poi\dots\ \gls{nomeVoce}

\end{document}
```

You can reproduce this result without using the option `acronym?` From the documentation it seems to me that you understand that we can do, but I did not succeed even after several attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Just load the `glossaries` package as

```
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
```

and then write

```
\renewcommand*{\acronymtype}{acronym}
\newglossary[alg]{acronym}{acr}{acn}{\acronymname}
```

Thus, if you rewrite your example as:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% !TEX program = pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\acronimo}[1]{%
  \mbox{\sffamily\scshape\MakeLowercase{#1}}}

\usepackage{xcolor}
    \colorlet{grigioScuro}{gray!75!black}
    \colorlet{grigioChiaro}{gray!95!black}
    \colorlet{grigioSfondo}{gray!12!white}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 0,pdfstartpage=1,pdftitle={Titolo PDF},pdfauthor={Nome Cognome},hidelinks,unicode}

\usepackage{xifthen,xkeyval,xfor,amsgen}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols} %su più colonne

\renewcommand*{\acronymtype}{acronym}
\newglossary[alg]{acronym}{acr}{acn}{\acronymname}
\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textcolor{gray}{\textsf{\MakeLowercase #1}}}
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{{\color{grigioScuro}\sffamily\scshape\MakeLowercase #1}}
\addto\captionsitalian{%
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryname}{Glossario}%
 \renewcommand*{\acronymname}{Acronimi}%
 \renewcommand*{\entryname}{Nomenclatura}%
 \renewcommand*{\descriptionname}{Descrizione}%
 \renewcommand*{\symbolname}{Simbolo}%
 \renewcommand*{\pagelistname}{Elenco delle pagine}%
 \renewcommand*{\glssymbolsgroupname}{Simboli}%
 \renewcommand*{\glsnumbersgroupname}{Numeri}
}

\ProvidesDictionary{glossaries-dictionary}{Italian}
\providetranslation{Glossary}{Glossario}

\renewcommand*{\glossaryentrynumbers}[1]{\quad #1}

    %su più colonne
    \renewcommand*{\glsmcols}{2}
    \glossarystyle{mcolindex}

\newacronym{fem}{fem}{Finite Element Method}

\newglossaryentry{nomeVoce}{name={nome voce},description={Descrizione della voce}}

\begin{document}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\printglossary

\glsaddall

\end{document}
```

you will have

> [image]

i.e. the same result as in your example but without the option `acronym`.

Anyway I can't figure why you want to do that.

Comment: If I use the option acronym, it comes an error. However, even using the code you wrote, and then not using the acronym option, an error occurs:! No room for a new \write .
\alloc@ ...else \errmessage {No room for a new #2}
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.149 \end{document}
                    
?

Comment: @Marco87 nothing to do with the example you've provided... Does my MWE produces any error for you?

Comment: @Marco87 if you need more help, provide some more info.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not reproduce the error with an example. Even using the same preamble of my thesis, together with all my personal definitions, the example I'm trying to do does not give me problems. I find only problems with the actual text of my thesis. I will make other attempts in order to be able to give an example. Thank you so much in the meantime.

Comment: @Marco87 I'll be happy to help (if able to...) when you find the source of the problem. In the meantime, however, you could accept it since it answers your question.